# Publising Umbraco pages in development environment differs across clients

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

We're working on an Umbraco site - multiple development machines using a shared development database.

When one developers makes changes in the CMS to content and does a Save and Publish the change is reflected on his machine but not other development machines.

This doesn't seem to make sense as we're all looking at the same database.? We've tried doing an IIS reset to see if it's caching at work but this doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Any ideas what on earth could be going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Umbraco does a lot of caching, so it doesn't have to hit the database all the time. Normally, all of the published content is cached in an xml file at `App_Data\umbraco.config`. You just need to have your developers right click on the root of the content tree in the umbraco backoffice and click "Republish the entire site" to regenerate that xml cache on disk from the xml cache in the database.

You also might need to reindex your examine indexes. You can normally find the "Examine Management" dashboard on the developer section in the backoffice of umbraco. By default, there are three indexes: InternalMember, Internal, and External. Unless you have membership going on in your umbraco site, you can ignore that index. The External index is used mostly for site searches. The Internal index is much more critical. It is used to cache media. I believe it is also used in the backoffice, but I'm not 100% certain. Make sure that the Internal index is regenerated.

Remember that media files are stored in the `/media` directory by default. That means if developer 'A' uploads a file, the physical file won't show up on developer 'B's machine automatically.

I'll bet you there's some cool ways to set up load balancing to handle a caching for your dev setup. I'm pretty sure there are also ways to store the media in the database, so you don't have to worry about transferring them back and forth.

Comment: In regards to the media in the database, I would take a look at the Azure Blob Storage Provider package for umbraco. I haven't tried it myself, but if it doesn't solve the media transfer problem, I'll bet it would lend a lot of clues.